# MySQL import. #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql-error-1452

I've tried importing an SQL file into an empty database in PHP MyAdmin and I have been presented with the following error:

```
SQL query:

customer_eav_attribute` ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_CSTR_EAV_ATTR_ATTR_ID_EAV_ATTR_ATTR_ID` 
FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_id`)
REFERENCES `eav_attribute` (`attribute_id`) 
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE

MySQL said: Documentation

#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: 
a foreign key constraint fails (`example_db_name`.
`#sql-1ab1_b9d4`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CSTR_EAV_ATTR_ATTR_ID_EAV_ATTR_ATTR_ID` 
FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_id`) REFERENCES 
`eav_attribute` (`attribute_id`) ON DELETE 
CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCA)
```

I have no idea what it means, what do I need to do to fix this?

thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

might be due to the order of the create table statement in the SQL file, move the create statement of the reference table "eav_attribute" before add constraint statements